# PSPDFKit - Add bookmarks support

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I'm using PSPDFKit. I'm wondering if it is possible to add Bookmarks support, something like the bookmarks feature in iBooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PSPDFKit PDF SDK](http://pspdfkit.com/) does support it's own version of bookmarks. They are not defined in the PDF standard, so they are written to an external file (unlike e.g. ink or highlight annotations, who are written back into the PDF on saving)

There's also a bookmarks controller that you can show via your custom UI with simply opening the [PSPDFBookmarkViewController](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation/Classes/PSPDFBookmarkViewController.html).

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your reply. The "Faked" way it's what i was looking for. I just sended you a mail because i have a doubt with another thing.

Comment: The features introduced in v2 are great. Thank you.